Outgoing ssh connection to the not-standard SSH port not working from guest OS
I'm newer int the libvirt.
I have Rocky Linux 9 guest os and host os ubuntu 24.
I trying to connect by ssh from the guest to the host in global network. I use the command "ssh -p 2222 admin@internet-hostname.net"
Have this error after long timeout:
"ssh: connect to host internet-hostname.net port 2222: Connection timed out"
I checked - resolving DNS name working fine, the ping also working. In addition to this I can connect to the same host (for example: internet-hostname.net) use standard TCP 22 port.
So, I think the issue happens only when I trying to connect non-standard ssh port.
Of course, I'm sure that the host internet-hostname.net can working on not-standard SSH port TCP 2222.
I checked it from the host machine using the same command, and it's working fine.
My guest machine uses "NAT" network type in libvirt...
Could someone give me some troubleshooting point?
Output from my host machine
$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for klim:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.122.8        tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.122.10       tcp dpt:ssh
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68

